# how to solve repeat data

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I'm new in codeigniter my question is how to solve repeating data when I use two foreach loops inside each other. When I use loop then it's repeat data and when use loops value outside the loop then it's print only last value how to solve.

```
 if ($invoiceResult->to_type == 'customer') 
        {
            $prodIds = isset($invoiceResult->pIds) && !empty($invoiceResult->pIds) ? rtrim($invoiceResult->pIds, ',') : '0';
            $stockIds = 0;
            if(isset($invoiceResult->sid) && $invoiceResult->sid != ' ')
            {
                $stockIds = rtrim($invoiceResult->sid, ',');
            }

            $printproduct = "SELECT p.pId,s.pId AS st_id, s.barcode, p.pPrice, p.pModel,p.HSNSAC,p.CGST,p.SGST,c.cName from  products p LEFT JOIN stock s ON p.pId = s.pId INNER JOIN category c ON p.cId = c.cId where s.sId IN (" . $stockIds . ") OR p.pId IN (" . $prodIds . ")";
            $query = $this->Main_model->__callMasterquery($printproduct);
            $printproresult = $query->result();
            $inVocRow = $query->row();
            $qtyResult = explode(",", $invoiceResult->pQtys);
        }
foreach ($printproresult as $key =>  $inVocRow ) 
        {

            $barcode = isset($inVocRow->barcode) ? $inVocRow->barcode : "N/A";

            $cgstRate = $inVocRow->CGST;
            $sgstRate = $inVocRow->SGST;
            $qty = ($inVocRow->barcode) ? 1 : $qtyResult[$key] ;
            print_r($qty);
            $prodPrice = ($inVocRow->barcode) ? $inVocRow->pPrice : $inVocRow->pPrice * $qty;


            $cgst = ((float)$prodPrice * $cgstRate) / 100;
            $sgst = ($prodPrice * $sgstRate) / 100;
            $cgstTotals += $cgst;
            $sgstTotals += $sgst;
            $gstRates += ($cgst + $sgst);
            $output .= '<tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);text-align:center;">' . $i++ . '</td>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0,0.125);text-align:center;">' . $inVocRow->cName . ': ' . $inVocRow->pModel . '</td>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);text-align:center;">' . $barcode . '</td>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0,0.125);text-align:center;">' . $inVocRow->HSNSAC . '</td>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0,0.125);text-align:center;">' . $Gst = $inVocRow->CGST + $inVocRow->SGST . '%</td>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);text-align:center;">' . $inVocRow->pPrice . '</td>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);text-align:center;"">' . $prodPrice . '</td>
                            <td style="border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>';
            $TotalAmount += $prodPrice;
        }exit();
```

Actually here is two type of product one is barcode and other is non barcode product. barcode product contains no quantity and non barcode product contains quantity. When I purchase both type of product then showing

> undefined offset:2 and undefined offset:3

because barcode product doesn't contain quantity. I find a solution that count the barcode product then use for loop and use quantity = 1 and add it in quantity array and multiply to product price but it repeats the value when I'm use it in foreach loop. If I use it before foreach loop then it prints only last value or if i use it in foreach loop then it is repeat and each quantity multiply each product price. How do I fix it. if any other type to solve quantity array please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in_array function to solve for example:-

```
$user = [];
if(in_array($user_data->mobile,$user)){
     $user[] = $user_data->mobile; @endphp
}else{
    '<option value="{{$user_data->mobile}}">'. ucfirst($user_data->name) .'</option>';
}
```